Is there any way/solution to disable xcrosshairs of missing values in apex chart?
Basically, I'm using sync chart of apex chart in that, i used null values where data is null in that time xcrosshair open, but i want that the crosshair open only when data is not null.
Please see below image in that the data is null still crosshair open.
Disable some legends to reproduce the issue see below screenshot.
Refer: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/null-values/
enter image description here

You can disable and re-enable the tooltip's xcrosshairs (and/or the tooltip title and/or the xaxis tooltip, and other components,
but these are the only visible one in the case of an all-null data point) directly through code, depending on the existence or not
of non-null data points. That can be done in any function that is sure to be invoked before the tooltip is displayed,
for instance in tooltip.x.formatter:
const options = {
    // ........ other option entries

    tooltip:{
        x: {
            formatter(value, {series, dataPointIndex}){
                const nNonNull = series.map(data => data[dataPointIndex])
                    .filter(x => x!==null).length;
                if(nNonNull === 0){
                    this.tooltip.xaxisTooltip.style.display = 'none';
                    this.tooltip.getElXCrosshairs().style.display = 'none';
                    this.tooltip.tooltipTitle.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else{
                    this.tooltip.xaxisTooltip.style.display = '';
                    this.tooltip.getElXCrosshairs().style.display = '';
                    this.tooltip.tooltipTitle.style.display = '';
                }

                return value;
            }
        }
    },
}

Here's a version of the example linked to in the question, using this approach:


const options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Peter',
        data: [5, 5, 10, null, null, null, null, 9, 10]
    }, {
        name: 'Johnny',
        data: [10, 15, null, null, null, 10, 12, 15, 11]
    }, {
        name: 'David',
        data: [1, 3, 1, null, null, 4, 1, 3, 4]
    }],
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'line',
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        },
        animations: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    stroke: {
        width: [5,5,4],
        curve: 'straight'
    },
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    title: {
        text: 'Missing data (null values)'
    },
    xaxis: {
    },
    tooltip:{
        x: {
            formatter(value, {series, dataPointIndex}){
                const nNonNull = series.map(data => data[dataPointIndex]).filter(x => x!==null).length;
                if(nNonNull === 0){
                    this.tooltip.xaxisTooltip.style.display = 'none';
                    this.tooltip.getElXCrosshairs().style.display = 'none';
                    this.tooltip.tooltipTitle.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else{
                    this.tooltip.xaxisTooltip.style.display = '';
                    this.tooltip.getElXCrosshairs().style.display = '';
                    this.tooltip.tooltipTitle.style.display = '';
                }

                return value;
            }
        }
    }
};

(new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options)).render();
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>



